# “Great advancement” vs. “Great advancements”

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

1. I have seen great advancement in technology in recent times.
2. I have seen great advancements in technology in recent times.

What is the difference between #1, and #2? To me, both seem to mean “advancement in general”. Is there any specific difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"great advancement in technology" means an overall improvement of technology, technology moving to a higher level.

"great advancements in technology" means several, or possibly many changes in technology, each of which is an imporovement.

In context the meaning is not much different. The singular form is looking at the "level" of technology as a single measure, and saying it has improved a lot. The plural  form is looking at individual changes and saying that there have been a number of them, each of which ism a significant improvement. As technology is in fact made up of many aspects each of which may have multiple separate details, one of these pretty much implies the other, the difference is one of emphasis, and of style.